# Log-Log in panel data for multiple regression

Tags: regression, logarithm

I'm using a model, for an article, with 6 independent variables. I used the logarithmic transformation of the dependent variable (Y) and 2 of the 6 independent variables. One of my professors said this could be done, but I remain uncertain. Can I do this? Also, one of my log variables had a negative coefficient, is that possible? My model is like this:
$$
\ln Y= B_0 + 2.07X_1 - 0.39\ln X_2 - 9.09 X_3 -4.4X_4 + 1\ln X_5
$$
The log transformed variables are: $Y$, $-039\ln X_2$, and $1\ln X_5$.  Is it possible do that?

I already know the functions and benefits of log-log, lin-log and log-lin model. I only want to know if its possible do what i did in my model

Comment: Welcome to our site.  If your computer returned an answer, then it proved that what you did was possible.  Whether it makes any *sense* or is *meaningful* or *interpretable* is a different question--but that's one we cannot answer without knowing more about your variables, the data, and the purpose of the analysis.

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/375885/log-log-model-for-regression this one is much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly take the log of some variables and not others; that's quite commonly done. As @whuber said in a comment, the fact that your computer gave an answer is proof it can be done.  Whether it is sensible is, also as he said, another matter.

However, as you have it written, what you wrote is not what you did.  That is, your model (as written) says that you took the log of $y, x_2, and x_5 $ but what you wrote is that you took the log of $-0.39 x_2$. If that's what you did, you would have to write $ln(-0.39 x_2)$ and you would have to be sure $x_2$ was always negative.